# Merge SwiftyJSON Nested Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON in Swift and I have two arrays that I would like to merge together.

These are the arrays that I have:

```
var array1 = JSON([
    "Cookie" : [
        "Active" : false,
        "Value" : 0
    ]
var array2 = JSON([
    "Candy" : [
        "Active" : false,
        "Value" : 0
    ]
```

What is the best way to achieve the result below when I print the array?

```
{
    "Cookie" : {
        "Active" : false,
        "Value" : 0
    },
    "Candy" : {
        "Active" : false,
        "Value" : 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind a FlattenBidirectionalCollection you can use

```
let array3 = [array1, array2].flatten()
```

which is less expensive.

or this

```
let array3 = [array1, array2].flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: Both of these options seem to work for what I need.  I had to change `flatten` to `joined` however.  Thanks!